# How to not show single quote in id attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 Razor view.
I have following code

```
@{
var count =0;
<input type="text" id="name'@count'" />

// Some more html elements 

}
```

Now, when i view this html in browser the ID of text element is showing `id="name'0'"`

How to not show the single quotes in id attribute.

Like this

```
id="name0"
```

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
@{
    var count= 0;

    <input type="text" id="name@{@count}" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
<input type="text" id="Name@(@count)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing it in a javascript file ,while defining you id make use of '+' operator
Ex: id="name"+"@count"

Comment: It is not Javascript, please check the Tags